# Help finding integer squares in parametric quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics, parametric

Find all integer $a$ such as equation $x^2 - 2019x + 2018a + 1 = 0$ has integer roots.
Tried to solve it by using Vieta theorem. Here is what I got:
$$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2=-2019\\
x_1*x_2=2018a+1\end{cases}$$
$$x_1*x_2 + x_1+x_2=2018a-2018$$
$$x_1*x_2 + x_1+x_2=2018(a-1)$$
Here I'm stuck

Comment: What do you mean by "integer squares". Please be as precise as you can.

Comment: Maybe roots are meant. In this case, both roots has to be integer or one at least?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Both roots have to be integer

Answer (score 0):

If there are integer roots meant:
$x^2 - 2019x + 2018a + 1$ [$=(x-\frac{2019}{2})^2+\frac14 (8072 a - 4076357)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+-+2019x+%2B+2018a+%2B+1-%28x-2019%2F2%29%5E2)
So $4076357-8072 a$ has to be $\ge0$ and a perfect square.
As $8072=8\cdot 1009$ and $n^2$ can only give remainders $0,1,4$ modulo $8$, but $4076357\equiv 5\pmod 8$, so $4076357-8072 a$ can't be a perfect square.
Answer: $\emptyset$ (no such $a$ exists)